# How to Create Product filter based of checkbox in angular

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, object, filter

I want to make a checkbox filter, where I have a list of Crops and List of Districts.

As you can see below :

[image]

Want I want in actual is like, When I **uncheck the RICE** on the right hand side it should I hide all the District name which having RICE. Also I want to add filter logic to District checkbox like When I uncheck Thane, on right hand side its should hide the Rice card which contain Thane only not all the Rice Card.

I tried the logic, but when I edited my array of Object its showing Two Checkboxes. I dont want two Checkboxes with same name.
Let me show you my output:

[image]

Here I am sharing my code base with you guys :

**1. crop.model.ts**

```
export class Crop {
    name: string;
    checked: boolean;
    district: string
    subCategory: Subcategory[];
}

export class Subcategory {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    checked: boolean;
}
```

**2. crop.data.ts**

```
import { Crop } from "./crop.model";

export const CROPS: Crop[] = [
    {
        name: "Rice",    // I want this Rice 
        checked: true,
        district: "Thane",
        subCategory: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: "Basmati",
                checked: true
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: "Ammamore",
                checked: true
            }
        ]
    }, {
        name: "Rice",  // also this one but on clicking on single Checkbox with name as Rice
        checked: true,
        district: "Nashik ",
        subCategory: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: "Basmati",
                checked: true
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: "Ammamore",
                checked: true
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "Wheat",
        checked: true,
        district: "Nashik",
        subCategory: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: "Durum",
                checked: true
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: "Emmer",
                checked: true
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "Barley",
        checked: true,
        district: "Ratnagiri",
        subCategory: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: "Hulless Barley",
                checked: true
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: "Barley Flakes",
                checked: true
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

**3. crop.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

import { Observable, of } from "rxjs";

import { Crop } from "../shared/crop.model";
import { CROPS } from "../shared/crop.data";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class CropService {
  constructor() { }

  crops: Crop[] = CROPS;

  getAllCrops(): Observable<Crop[]> {
    return of(this.crops);
  }

  getCrop(name: string): Observable<any> {
    const crop = this.crops.filter(crop => crop.name === name)[0];

    return of(crop);
  }
}
```

**4. all-trades.component.html**

```
<app-header></app-header>
<div
  fxLayout="row"
  fxLayout.lt-md="column"
  fxLayoutAlign="space-between start"
  fxLayoutAlign.lt-md="start stretch"
>
  <div class="container-outer" fxFlex="20">
    <div class="filters">
      <section class="example-section">
        <span class="example-list-section">
          <h1>Select Crop</h1>
        </span>
        <span class="example-list-section">
          <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let crop of crops$ | async">
              <mat-checkbox
                [checked]="crop.checked"
                (change)="onChange($event, i, crop)"
              >
                {{ crop.name }}
              </mat-checkbox>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </span>
      </section>

      <section class="example-section">
        <span class="example-list-section">
          <h1>Select District</h1>
        </span>
        <span class="example-list-section">
          <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let crop of crops$ | async">
              <mat-checkbox
                [checked]="crop.checked"
                (change)="onChange($event, i, crop)"
              >
                {{ crop.district }}
              </mat-checkbox>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </span>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content container-outer" fxFlex="80">
    <mat-card
      class="crop-card"
      style="min-width: 17%"
      *ngFor="let crop of crops$ | async"
      [hidden]="!crop.checked"
    >
      <a [routerLink]="[crop.name]">
        <mat-card-header>
          <img
            mat-card-avatar
            class="example-header-image"
            src="/assets/icons/crops/{{ crop.name }}.PNG"
            alt="crop-image"
          />
          <mat-card-title>{{ crop.name }}</mat-card-title>
          <mat-card-subtitle>100 Kgs</mat-card-subtitle>
        </mat-card-header>
      </a>
      <mat-card-content>
        <p>PRICE</p>
      </mat-card-content>
      <mat-card-content>
        <p>{{ crop.district }}</p>
      </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
  </div>
</div>

<app-footer></app-footer>
```

**5. all-trades.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Crop } from 'src/app/shared/crop.model';
import { CropService } from '../crop.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-all-trades',
  templateUrl: './all-trades.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./all-trades.component.css'],
})
export class AllTradesComponent implements OnInit {

  crops$: Observable<Crop[]>;

  constructor(private cropService: CropService) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.crops$ = this.cropService.getAllCrops();
  }
  onChange(event, index, item) {
    item.checked = !item.checked;
    console.log(index, event, item);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faisal.

Perhaps this
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ehewbb?file=src/app/app.component.ts)  will help you with your problem.

I think, it is possible to fix your problem without using the forms. I have split filter logic and data into observables. The new filteredCrops$ observable will combine latest data from crops$, and 2 Behavior subjects with filters. Than crops data array sill be filtered using function which returns true, if filters for this particular crop name and district are truthy (i.e. checked).

**1. app.component.ts**

```
interface Filter {
  name: string;
  checked: boolean;
}

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  crops$: Observable<Crop[]>;
  filteredCrops$: Observable<Crop[]>;
  nameFilters$ = new BehaviorSubject<Filter[]>([]);
  districtFilters$ = new BehaviorSubject<Filter[]>([]);
  filteredDistrictCheckboxes$: Observable<Filter[]>;

  constructor(private cropService: CropService) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.crops$ = this.cropService.getAllCrops().pipe(
      tap(crops => {
        const names = Array.from(new Set(crops.map(crop => crop.name)));
        this.nameFilters$.next(
          names.map(name => ({ name, checked: true } as Filter))
        );
        const dictricts = Array.from(new Set(crops.map(crop => crop.district)));
        this.districtFilters$.next(
          dictricts.map(name => ({ name, checked: true } as Filter))
        );
      })
    );
    this.filteredCrops$ = combineLatest(
      this.crops$,
      this.nameFilters$,
      this.districtFilters$
    ).pipe(
      map(
        ([crops, nameFilters, districtFilters]: [
          Crop[],
          Filter[],
          Filter[]
        ]) => {
          let items = [...crops];
          items = items.filter(item => {
            const associatedNameFilter = nameFilters.find(
              filter => filter.name === item.name
            );
            const associatedDistrictFilter = districtFilters.find(
              filter => filter.name === item.district
            );
            return (
              associatedNameFilter.checked && associatedDistrictFilter.checked
            );
          });
          return items;
        }
      )
    );

    this.filteredDistrictCheckboxes$ = this.nameFilters$.pipe(
      switchMap((nameFilters: Filter[]) => {
        return this.crops$.pipe(
          map(crops => {
            const enabledNames = nameFilters
              .filter(item => item.checked)
              .map(filter => filter.name);
            const enabledDistricts = Array.from(new Set(crops.filter(crop => enabledNames.includes(crop.name)).map(crop => crop.district)));
            const result = this.districtFilters$.value.filter(item =>
              enabledDistricts.includes(item.name)
            );
            return result;
          })
        );
      })
    );
  }

  onNameFilterChange(item) {
    this.nameFilters$.value.find(
      filter => filter.name === item.name
    ).checked = !item.checked;
    this.nameFilters$.next([...this.nameFilters$.value]);
  }

  onDistrictFilterChange(item) {
    this.districtFilters$.value.find(
      filter => filter.name === item.name
    ).checked = !item.checked;
    this.districtFilters$.next([...this.districtFilters$.value]);
  }
}
```

**2. Template from app.component.html**

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayout.lt-md="column" fxLayoutAlign="space-between start" fxLayoutAlign.lt-md="start stretch"
    *ngIf="crops$ | async">
    <div class="container-outer" fxFlex="20">
        <div class="filters">
            <section class="example-section">
                <span class="example-list-section">
          <h1>Select Crop</h1>
        </span>
                <span class="example-list-section">
          <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let filter of nameFilters$ | async">
              <mat-checkbox
                [checked]="filter.checked"
                (change)="onNameFilterChange(filter)"
              >
                {{ filter.name }}
              </mat-checkbox>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </span>
            </section>

            <section class="example-section">
                <span class="example-list-section">
          <h1>Select District</h1>
        </span>
                <span class="example-list-section">
          <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let filter of filteredDistrictCheckboxes$ | async">
              <mat-checkbox
                [checked]="filter.checked"
                (change)="onDistrictFilterChange(filter)"
              >
                {{ filter.name }}
              </mat-checkbox>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </span>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content container-outer" fxFlex="80">
        <mat-card class="crop-card" style="min-width: 17%" *ngFor="let crop of filteredCrops$ | async"
            [hidden]="!crop.checked">
            <a [routerLink]="[crop.name]">
                <mat-card-header>
                    <img
            mat-card-avatar
            class="example-header-image"
            src="/assets/icons/crops/{{ crop.name }}.PNG"
            alt="crop-image"
          />
                    <mat-card-title>{{ crop.name }}</mat-card-title>
                    <mat-card-subtitle>100 Kgs</mat-card-subtitle>
                </mat-card-header>
            </a>
            <mat-card-content>
                <p>PRICE</p>
            </mat-card-content>
            <mat-card-content>
                <p>{{ crop.district }}</p>
            </mat-card-content>
        </mat-card>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome ! Alexey, but in select district its still showing two Nashik checkbox. In stackbliz its showing one checkbox of Nashik district but when I implementing on my code its showing two checkboxes of nashik

Comment: By the way thanx... and also I follow you on github and request you on linkedin hope you wont mind 

Comment: Faisal, perhaps i have not understand your problem completely right. Do you want that after crop name select, checkboxes in District section should contain the only districts which have selected crops? This way you need one more observable for the districts checkbox list. I'll try to update my stackblitz.

Comment: Faisal, see updated stackblitz or code in answer above.

I added filteredDistrictCheckboxes$ observable with the code for it in nOnInit method. Also the template is updated with the new variable for the district checkboxes list.